# Is there anyone who can help me to install maatwebsite/excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I have tried to install composer require maatwebsite/excel and I have tried several times but still getting errors and I'm using laravel 9.23.0 and PHP v8.0.5 here is the error.

Using version ^3.1 for maatwebsite/excel
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update maatwebsite/excel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.36, ..., 3.1.x-dev] require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.18 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.24.1].
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.25] require php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.0.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
- maatwebsite/excel[3.1.26, ..., 3.1.35] require illuminate/support 5.8.*|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> found illuminate/support[v5.8.0, ..., 5.8.x-dev, v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev, v8.0.0, ..., 8.x-dev] but these were not loaded, likely because it
conflicts with another require.
- phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.18.0, ..., 1.24.1] require ext-gd * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's
gd extension.
- Root composer.json requires maatwebsite/excel ^3.1 -> satisfiable by maatwebsite/excel[3.1.0, ..., 3.1.x-dev].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
- C:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-gd` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require maatwebsite/excel:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require maatwebsite/excel:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

Comment: do as the error said, use php 7.* and enable/install the extension ext-gd. what is not clear? it says in their github https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel that it only supports up to laravel 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [docs](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/getting-started/installation.html) the requirements are:

- PHP: `^7.2\|^8.0`
- Laravel: `^5.8|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0`
- PhpSpreadsheet: `^1.21`
- psr/simple-cache: `^1.0`
- PHP extension `php_zip` enabled
- PHP extension `php_xml` enabled
- PHP extension `php_gd2` enabled
- PHP extension `php_iconv` enabled
- PHP extension `php_simplexml` enabled
- PHP extension `php_xmlreader` enabled
- PHP extension `php_zlib` enabled

Go to the `php.ini` file by you xampp console. [image] Search this `;extension=gd` and remove `;` then restart the server.
Check if the other php extension are enabled to.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message mentioning it the **PHP GD extension is missing** on your system.

Google for `install php gd` for you system `windows`, `mac`, `linux` and follow the installation instructions.

For `linux` it will be:

```
sudo apt-get install php8.0-gd
```

If you are using a `docker` container, then you can use the following:

```
COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/
RUN install-php-extensions gd
```

After the gd extension is installed try to install the package again. If it fails check if there is another package missing and install it in a similar way.